# RequireJS + Algolia Docsearch throws mismatched anonymous define()..error

Tags: javascript, search, requirejs, algolia

I am trying to implement Algolia Docsearch with MadCap Flare. Flare is a technical documentation tool that generates HTML output.

Docsearch's underlying crawler is configured and works properly in codepen. However, I am having an issue integrating it with Flare. Flare has a number of inbuilt scripts, which I cannot access or change, including **require.js**. I get a bunch of errors, **Uncaught Error: Mismatched anonymous define() module..**, when I run the build.

So to fix this, I gave a stab at loading the Docsearch js using `require.js`, which I am doing completely wrong. My JS knowledge is limited!

Html search input:

```
<div class="input-group">
    <input id="<YOUR_CSS_SELECTOR>"  type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search Field" aria-describedby="infoSearch" />
</div>
```

Original Algolia Docsearch CDN js and snippet is something like this:

```
<!-- Before the closing </body> -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/docsearch.js@2/dist/cdn/docsearch.min.js">
    </script>
    <script>
    docsearch({
        apiKey: '<API_KEY>',
        indexName: '<INDEX_NAME>',
        inputSelector: '<YOUR_CSS_SELECTOR>',
        debug: false
    });
    </script>
```

So to load these scripts using `require.js` I have done the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
require.config({
    enforceDefine: true,
    paths: {
        "docSearch": "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/docsearch.js@2/dist/cdn/docsearch.min.js"
    },
    waitSeconds: 40
});
require(['docSearch']);//This is probably not doing anything.
</script>
<script>
docsearch({
    apiKey: '<API_KEY>',
    indexName: '<INDEX_NAME>',
    inputSelector: '<YOUR_CSS_SELECTOR>',
    debug: false
}); //This throws "Uncaught Reference Error docsearch is not defined" error
</script>
```

I looked at other threads/questions and require.js docs as well, but couldn't find something that could figure out. Any help/guidance would be great!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should include something like

```
    <script>
/* <![CDATA[ */

require.config( {
    paths: {
        "docsearchLib": "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/docsearch.js/2/docsearch.min"
    }
}

);
require(["docsearchLib"], function(docsearch) {
    docsearch( {
        apiKey: '<API_KEY>', indexName: '<INDEX_NAME>', inputSelector: '<YOUR_CSS_SELECTOR>', debug: false,
    }
    );
}

);
/* ]]> */

</script>
```

You might want to have a look to https://docs.solace.com/, they are actually using DocSearch and require.js altogether